# Does ZF set language has first order struct?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

Hi I'm learning mathematical logic and set theory.

As far as I know, set language is a first order language, which means it may have a first order structure.

However, the first order structure is defined using set $<M,I>$.

By a very simple assumption, I may think that $M$ is the set of all sets. So that we can construct our variable assignment.

But by ZF's Axioms, it denies the existence of such set that including all sets.

Thus I would like to ask if set language have a first order structure. If yes, what is the $M$. If not, how to prove the logical consequences since with first order structure, we can prove it by satisfaction.

---

As far as I know, set language is a first order language consist of the following symbols:

1. variable symbols
2. $p_\in$ as the only relation symbol
3. $=$ as equality symbol
4. $\forall,\exists$ as Quantifier symbols
5. $\to,\leftrightarrow,\lnot,\lor,\land$ as logic connectives

As far as I know that for first order language:

1. there can be a first order structure $\mathcal{M}=<M, I>$, where $I$ is used to explain $\in$ symbol
2. based on 1, it can form a variable assignment function $v:X\to M$
3. based on 1 & 2, it can then extend $v$ to $\bar{v}:T\to M$ where $T$ is all the terms
4. furthermore, we can evaluate the truth of expressions, such as $p_\in(a,b)$ is true if and only if $<v(a),v(b)>\in I(p_\in)$

Comment: The “set” $M$ for the model is coming from a “meta-theory”.

Comment: If ZF is consistent, then it has a model (i.e. there is a structure $(M, I)$ satisfying all the ZF axioms.) But there’s no reason to expect such a model to consist of all sets… and every reason to expect the opposite, since as you say, there is no set of all sets. In fact, in general model-theoretic grounds there will be many different models of ZF of every infinite size.

Comment: @joe where I can find out more about the “meta-theory”

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen What u mean is that there is a first order struct, but $M$ may not be limited by ZF language it self. Or there are many structures $<M_1,I_1>,<M_2,I_2>,...$ that satisfy set theory??

Comment: @Shore yes, if ZF is consistent, then there are indeed many structures modeling it. in fact if it is consistent then there proper class many non-isomorphic models of it. (this is true of any first-order theory, as spaceisdarkgreen points out)

Comment: @Shore Not sure what you mean by "$M$ may not be limited by ZF language itself", but to the latter, yes, I mean there are many structures that satisfy the ZF axioms. Just like there are many structures that satisfy the axioms of group theory (i.e. groups) or many structures that satisfy the order axioms (i.e. linearly ordered sets). I would also suggest searching this site for "models of set theory" or something like that... variants of this question have been asked many times.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I mean that there is a full set $M$ that does not consist with ZF axioms, by that assumption we can have a structure $<M,I>$ to cover all set. Otherwise $M$ should be carefully constructed to include the targeted sets and do not create conflict with axioms

Comment: A structure for a language does not have to be a model for ZF or for any particular theory.

Comment: @danielwainfleet which means we can have a structure for ZF language that does not consist with ZF's axiom??

Comment: @Shore your definition above doesn’t say anything about the axioms, right? It can be any set and any binary relation to interpret $\in$. For instance, $M$ can be the real numbers and $I$ can be $<$. You will see that this happens to satisfy several ZF axioms and fails to satisfy some others.

Comment: A structure for the language is only an "interpretation" of its symbols. If a structure satisfies a theory (a collection of axioms), we call it a model for that theory.